# Index out of range exception in 2D Array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, indexoutofboundsexception

```
char[,] map = new char[10, 20];

for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < map.GetLength(1); j++)
        map[i, j] = '.';
}
```

I just simply want to make all the elements of map[i,j] to be a point , but always when I try to run it the compiler says: Index out of range exception. Maybe it's a stupid question but I had to ask it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the `i` in your j-loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
```

Comment: Thank you!And that proves that it was a silly question, thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

You use `i` instead of `j` look at this:

```
char[,] map = new char[10, 20];

for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        map[i, j] = '.';
    }
}
```